# C# запуск консольного приложения из программы.

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть необходимость запустить консольное приложение из своей программы. Но так, чтобы эта консоль НЕ закрывалась после вызова. А то, только и видно, что консоль запустилась и сразу же закрылась. Желательно, чтобы консоль не отображалась. То есть, работала в скрытом режиме.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("путь к консольному приложению");
```

И желательно запускать, а точнее, даже важно, запускать приложение с командой.
В виже: **путь-к-программеconsole.exe --conamd**

Спасибо за помощь. Всем хорошего настроения. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
//создание параметров
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        //имя файла
                        FileName = "fileName.exe",
                        //скрытое окно
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        //ваши аргументы
                        Arguments = "-command"                    
                     };
//запуск процесса
Process.Start(startInfo);
```